# Tablas temporal en procedimiento almacenado Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-cursores

Tengo que hacer un reporte en el cual comparo los valores presupuestados y los valores reales de los gastos.

Para esto quiero usar una tabla temporal en un procedimineto almacenado, en esta tabla voy insertando los datos que necesito para luego retornar todo lo que de esta tabla.

Intento hacer este procedimiento almacenado

```
drop procedure if exist sp_presupuesto;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_presupuesto(IN panio varchar(4))
BEGIN
CREATE temporary TABLE tmppresupuestos(
      preid int,
      precod varchar(100),
      precue varchar(200),
      ene numeric,
      feb numeric,
      mar numeric,
      abr numeric,
      may numeric,
      jun numeric,
      jul numeric,
      ago numeric,
      sep numeric,
      oct numeric,
      nov numeric,
      dic numeric,
      tot numeric,
      primary key(preid)
  );
  
  DECLARE v_catctamaecon varchar(100);
  DECLARE v_nomcta varchar(200);
  DECLARE v_ctamaecon varchar(100);
  DECLARE v_ctacontpre varchar(100);
  DECLARE v_anopre varchar(4);
  DECLARE v_valpre0 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre1 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre2 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre3 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre4 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre5 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre6 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre7 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre8 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre9 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre10 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valpre11 numeric;
  DECLARE v_valtotal numeric;
  
  DECLARE v_rene numeric;
  DECLARE v_rfeb numeric;
  DECLARE v_rmar numeric;
  DECLARE v_rabr numeric;
  DECLARE v_rmay numeric;
  DECLARE v_rjun numeric;
  DECLARE v_rago numeric;
  DECLARE v_rsep numeric;
  DECLARE v_roct numeric;
  DECLARE v_rnov numeric;
  DECLARE v_rdic numeric;

  
  DECLARE v_cuenta varchar(50);
  
  declare done int default false;
  declare total numeric;
  
  declare cur_presupuesto cursor for
    select catctamaecon,nomcta,ctamaecon,
                ctacontpre,anopre,valpre0,valpre1,valpre2,valpre3,valpre4,valpre5,valpre6,valpre7,valpre8,valpre9,valpre10,valpre11
    from maecon,maepre 
    where (catctamaecon like '4%' or  catctamaecon like '5%' ) and ctacontpre=ctamaecon
        and anopre=panio  order by ctamaecon ASC;

    declare continue HANDLER for not found set done = true;
    set total = 0;
    open cur_presupuesto;
    loop1:loop
      FETCH cur_presupuesto INTO v_ctacontpre,v_anopre,v_valpre0,v_valpre1,v_valpre2,v_valpre3,v_valpre4,v_valpre5,v_valpre6,v_valpre7,v_valpre8,v_valpre9,v_valpre10;
      
      if done then
             leave loop1;
      end if;
      -- inserto los valores del presupuesto
      
      set total = v_valpre0+v_valpre1+v_valpre2+v_valpre3+v_valpre4+v_valpre5+v_valpre6+v_valpre7+v_valpre8+v_valpre9+v_valpre10+v_valpre11;
      insert into tmppresupuestos( preid,precod,precue,ene,feb,mar,abr,may,jun,jul,ago,sep,oct,nov,dic,tot)
      values (1,ctamaecon,nomcta,v_valpre0,v_valpre1,v_valpre2,v_valpre3,v_valpre4,v_valpre5,v_valpre6,v_valpre7,v_valpre8,v_valpre9,v_valpre10,v_valpre11,total)
        
      -- inserto los valores reales

      set v_rene=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=1 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_rfeb=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=2 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_rmar=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=3 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_rabr=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=4 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_rmay=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=5 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_rjun=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=6 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_rjul=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=7 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_rago=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=8 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_rsep=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=9 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_roct=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=10 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_rnov=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=11 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set v_rdic=select sum(valorhis) FROM movcon WHERE ctahiscon=ctamaecon and MONTH(fechahis)=12 and year(fechahis)=panio and db1cr2his='1'
      set total = v_rene+v_rfeb+v_rmar+v_rabr+v_rmay+v_rjun+v_rjul+v_rago+v_rsep+v_roct+v_rnov+v_rdic;

      insert into tmppresupuestos( preid,precod,precue,ene,feb,mar,abr,may,jun,jul,ago,sep,oct,nov,dic,tot)
      values (1,ctamaecon,nomcta,v_rene,v_rfeb,v_rmar,v_rabr,v_rmay,v_rjun,v_rjul,v_rago,v_rsep,v_roct,v_rnov,v_rdic);
      
    end loop loop1;
    close cur_presupuesto;
    
    select * from tmppresupuestos;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

pero al ejecutar el codigo y crear el procedimiento almacenado me sale este error

```
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'DECLARE v_catctamaecon varchar(100);
  DECLARE v_nomcta varchar(200);
  DECLARE' en la linea 22
```

alguien que me pueda ayudar indicando que esta mal. y si la forma en la que estoy haciendo el procedimiento es la correcta, es decir usando cursores y tablas temporables?

Comment: Mira lo que dice mysql en [DECLARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html). La ejecución de una sentencia (como crear la tabla) no puede aparecer antes que la declaración de variables, que debe ir antes de la declaración de cursores, que debe ir antes de la declaración de handlers

Comment: gracias era el orden de la declaracion. saludos